# Using strings that contain ticks/quotes in an SQL command

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using

```
$shouldfollow = "'".htmlspecialchars($_GET["shouldfollow"])."',";
echo $shouldfollow;
```

to acheive a string similar to `'apple',`. It works 100% *so far*. The tricky part is trying to use that variable in a MySQL command. Here's what I've tried.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET following=".$shouldfollow." WHERE username='$username'");
```

But it instead says my syntax is wrong. I know the command will work how I want to (ie if I remove the `'',` part).

[image]

If I havent been confusingly redundant enough, the picture above is what my final result should be after running the command.

Comment: umm dont use `mysql_*` commands, you should use the PDO library and prepare your statements. This is a prime candidate for SQL injection. If you prepared your statement and sanitize inputs you should be fine.

Comment: @1337holiday: check the question once again? PS: "and sanitize inputs you should be fine" -- this part of your statement doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @1337holiday: *sighs*. `mysqli_query` - please read the function name once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use not `htmlspecialchars` which makes no sense for sql, but only for HTML, but [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Or, even better, [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

What about comma - you have to escape every variable at once:

```
$shouldfollow = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["shouldfollow"]);
```

or with prepared statements:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, 'UPDATE users SET following = ? WHERE username = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_GET["shouldfollow"], $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

**NOTE**: you still have to check if `$_GET["shouldfollow"]` exists additionally, but it's out of scope for this question.

Comment: Works good. Should I replace all of my `htmlspecialchars` for `$_GET` or is that the same issue?

Comment: @vectorquake: they are for different things. `htmlspecialchars` is to sanitize data before you output it to the browser. `mysqli_real_escape_string` is to sanitize data before you put it as a part of sql query. So there is no always correct function to use - you just pick the one that is correct for a particular usage context.